# How to get the transformation for a georeferenced dataset in azimuthal equidistant projection using rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio, affine-transformation

I have a squared Numpy array with `data`. I also have both squared arrays of the same shape with `lat` and `lon`. I also know the projection used by this data, an [azimuthal equidistant](https://proj.org/operations/projections/aeqd.html?highlight=aeqd) with known center latitude and longitude.

Is it possible write this data as a GeoTIFF file without interpolation, i.e. keeping the actual grid? The problem I have is that I should attach a the affine transformation for the grid. I guess I should use [`rasterio.transform.from_bounds`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.transform.html#rasterio.transform.from_bounds), but the problem is that I'm not sure what are the bounds here. After all, the data is not on a regular *latlon* projection, so in each point there are slighly different latitudes and longitudes. Which one should I use?

I know they are *almost equal* in each row/column, so I could choose some of them in the borders more or less arbitrarily, but I feel this is making a small mistake. Is there a way to write this data as a GeoTIFF preserving the raw grid information?